# i need to fix this python code so it generates a username i am a beginner so this is probably a simple fix im unaware of

Tags: python, arrays, string, integer

```
Fname=input("What is your forename? ")
Sname=input("What is your surname? ")
age=int,input("What is your age? ")
randNo=int(input("Enter a random number that is NO MORE that 2 digits: "))

if randNo >2 :
   print("NO MORE thant two digits!")


if len(randNo)<= 2:
 sn2= str.upper(Sname[0])
fn2=str.upper(Fname[0])
fnl2=str.lower(Fname[1:3])
ag2=int(age)
rn2=int(randNo)

userN=int,sn2+fn2+fnl2+ag2+rn2

print(userN)
```

the problem is about it having to be an integer or something like that

it give an error im not sure why

Comment: Please [edit] to at least show the _exact_ error message which shows which line is raising the error, rather than paraphrasing with "*or something like that*" and having people guess which specific problem you are asking.

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but think about what `userN=int,sn2+fn2+fnl2+ag2+rn2` is supposed to do. You have some of those as `int` and some as `str`,... so what do you expect to happen when adding strings and numbers? What is the expected output of that line? (Which is another thing you should [edit] into your question) And what does the syntax `int,` supposed to do?

Comment: You also have `age=int,input("What is your age? ")`, why is there a comma after `int`? Is it supposed to be `age=int(input(...))`? Because you created `age` as a tuple, then after you did `int(age)`, which will not work.

Comment: yes i realise i must be specific thanks for pointing that out.  im fairly new to this so i dont fully understand it but thank you i appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed all of the errors however there are still some spelling mistakes which you can fix at your discretion.

```py
Fname=input("What is your forename? ")
Sname=input("What is your surname? ")
age=int(input("What is your age? "))
randNo=int(input("Enter a random number that is NO MORE that 2 digits: "))

if randNo>2 :
   print("NO MORE thant two digits!")

randNo=str(randNo)
if len(randNo)<= 2:
    sn2= str.upper(Sname[0])
    fn2=str.upper(Fname[0])
    fnl2=str.lower(Fname[1:3])
    ag2=int(age)
    rn2=int(randNo)
ag2=str(ag2)
rn2=str(rn2)
userN=fn2+sn2+fnl2+ag2+rn2

print(userN)
```